# Convert JSON array to Python list

Tags: python, json, list

```py
import json

array = '{"fruits": ["apple", "banana", "orange"]}'
data  = json.loads(array)
```

That is my JSON array, but I would want to convert all the values in the `'fruits'` string to a Python list. What would be the correct way of doing this?

Comment: What do you mean? `data['fruits']` will be a list

Comment: You have a JSON _Object_ containing an _Array_. A JSON Array is homologous to a Python `list`. A JSON _Object_ is homologous to a Python `dict`. Technically, you have a `dict` containing a single key-value pair where the value is a `list` of strings.

Answer (score 160, accepted):

```
import json

array = '{"fruits": ["apple", "banana", "orange"]}'
data  = json.loads(array)
print data['fruits']
# the print displays:
# [u'apple', u'banana', u'orange']
```

You had everything you needed. `data` will be a dict, and `data['fruits']` will be a list

Answer (score 15):

[Tested on Ideone.](http://ideone.com/8qE6N)

```
import json
array = '{"fruits": ["apple", "banana", "orange"]}'
data  = json.loads(array)
fruits_list = data['fruits']
print fruits_list
```

Answer (score 3):

`ast.literal_eval()` from the Python standard library `ast` may be used to parse json strings as well.

It's especially useful if the string looks like a json but is actually a string representation of a Python object. In such cases, `json.loads` won't work but `ast.literal_eval` works.

```py
import ast
array = '{"fruits": ("apple", "banana", "orange")}'
a = ast.literal_eval(array)  # {'fruits': ('apple', 'banana', 'orange')}
j = json.loads(array)        # JSONDecodeError
```

Answer (score 0):

`data` will return you a **string representation** of a list, but it is actually still a string. Just check the type of `data` with `type(data)`. That means if you try using indexing on this string representation of a list as such `data['fruits'][0]`, it will return you "[" as it is the first character of `data['fruits']`

You can do `json.loads(data['fruits'])` to convert it back to a Python list so that you can interact with regular list indexing. There are 2 other ways you can convert it back to a Python list suggested [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/convert-a-string-representation-of-list-into-list-in-python)