# Extract information from a list inside a unicode string

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, unicode

```
>>> myUnicode 
[u'[X: $1.11] [Y: $3.33] [Z 0/1000]']
```

---

I have a Unicode string containing the above ^. I am attempting to extract the following lists:

```
[X: $1.11] 
[Y: $3.33]
```

And have them stored under separate variables.

---

*My Attempt*

My idea was to convert `myUnicode` into a list and get the values individually. I'm aware that this is a poor attempt but unfortunately I'm unable to think of an alternative method:

```
myUnicode = [myUnicode]
X = myUnicode[0]
Y = myUnicode[1]
```

But get the following error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

---

*My Ideal/Expected Output*

```
>>> X
X: $1.11

>>> Y
Y: $3.33
```

Comment: Try a list of dict where you ```key is x``` and ```value is $1.1``` for instead, then you can loop about list and get the value for x and y.

Comment: You might have to do some parsing and then load it into a Python data type using JSON.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10973614/convert-json-array-to-python-list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`myUnicode` list contains only **1 entry** which is a `string`, to achieve what you want, you can convert it to a dictionary, i.e.:

```
import re
myUnicode = [u'[X: $1.11] [Y: $3.33] [Z 0/1000]']
matches = re.findall(r"\[(.*?):?\s(.*?)]", myUnicode[0])
final_dict = {}
for x in matches:
    final_dict[x[0]] = x[1]
```

You can access the values with:

```
print final_dict['X'], final_dict['Y'], final_dict['Z']
# $1.11 $3.33 0/1000
```

---

[Demo](https://ideone.com/8dRGpc)

Comment: Thank You so much! This is great ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse the data somehow. Its easy to grab everything between two brackets using a regular expression. Since `[` is a special character for a regex it needs to be escaped. `\[([^\]]+)` will find an opening bracket and then group everything up to the next closing bracket. Use it with `re.findall` and you'll get all of your "lists". This code will add them to the module's namespace

```
>>> import re
>>> myUnicode = [u'[X: $1.11] [Y: $3.33] [Z 0/1000]']
>>> for code in re.findall(ur'\[([^\]]+)', myUnicode[0]):
...     if u':' in code:
...         k, v = code.split(u':', 1)
...         globals()[str(k.strip())] = v.strip()
... 
>>> X
u'$1.11'
>>> Y
u'$3.33'
```

Putting them in the global namespace is odd (how does the rest of your program know what names where added) and can be dangerous. Non-ascii variables or variables with other illegal characters shouldn't go there. You could create your own dict to hold them

```
>>> myvars = {}
>>> for code in re.findall(ur'\[([^\]]+)', myUnicode[0]):
...     if u':' in code:
...         k, v = code.split(u':', 1)
...         myvars[k.strip()] = v.strip()
... 
>>> myvars[u"X"]
u'$1.11'
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks! =) /TooShort

Answer (score 0):

If you want this specific `Output` you can iterate over list and then cut  string with `[:]`:

```
myunicode = [u'[X: $1.11] [Y: $3.33] [Z 0/1000]']
for data in myunicode:
    x =  data[1:8]
    y =  data[12:19]
    print x
    print y
```

Comment: That doesn't give me the right output: `X: $1.1
Y: $3.3
X: $1.1
Y: $3.3`