# Convert dataframe values to a 1D list

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to graph with chart.js and need to convert my json string to a list
but i am not able to

this is `df2`:

```
df2

   AQPSD  ASD  CO  ECARS  ED  EO  ISD  MSCD  OIS  RD  TTD
0      6    8   2      3   6   4    4     5    1   2    4
```

My desired output is `[6, 8, 2, 3, 6, 4, 4, 5, 1, 2, 4]`

---

Relevant code:

```
"""
qry = """
SELECT [Employee Name], Department, [Date Assigned] FROM MyTable Where CompletedTraining = 'Incomplete' ORDER BY Department ASC
"""

df2 = pd.read_sql_query(qry, con)

## verify data from query
result = df.set_index('Department').to_json()
print(result[0].values.tolist())
```

`result` is my current output, but it is a dictionary, not a list. How can I fix this?

Comment: I don't really get your problem. What is your expected output?

Comment: Also, what is your `df3` looking like? please post some sample data as text.

Comment: I posted df3, {"AQPSD":6,"ASD":8,"CO":2,"ECARS":3,"ED":6,"EO":4,"ISD":4,"MSCD":5,"OIS":1,"RD":2,"TTD":4}} im trying to graph this in charts.js so i assume i need just the values

Comment: That's not a dataframe, that's a dict. Also, what is your _expected output_?

Comment: thats what df3 is..., i need the values to the right of the department in a list, so [6, 8, 2, 3, 6, 4, 4, 5, 1, 2, 4]

Comment: How about doing `df.set_index('Department').values().ravel().tolist()` instead?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 48, in <module>
    df.set_index('Department').values().tolist()
TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert JSON array to Python list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10973614/convert-json-array-to-python-list)

Comment: Sorry, it's values, not values()

Comment: it still doesn't like it :(  keep getting keyError: 'department'  print(df.set_index('department').values.ravel().tolist())

Comment: This works! print(df.values.ravel().tolist())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it seems like you have a dataframe looking like this -

```
df

   AQPSD  ASD  CO  ECARS  ED  EO  ISD  MSCD  OIS  RD  TTD
0      6    8   2      3   6   4    4     5    1   2    4
```

If you want these values as a single list, you can call `.values` and convert to a list -

```
df.values.ravel().tolist()
```

Or,

```
df.values.flatten().tolist()
```

```
[6, 8, 2, 3, 6, 4, 4, 5, 1, 2, 4]
```

Comment: print(df2.values.ravel().tolist()) this works, i already posted above, is it possible to include the 0 everyone completed the training? currently it doesn't include that in my list

Comment: @davidjbeiler You want to include the index?

Comment: no... just a value of 0 if there's no incompletes, ie everyone took the training i need to be able to graph that

Comment: @davidjbeiler Okay, you mean you have NaNs in your data which you want to replace with 0?

Comment: yeah, but it doesn't even show the naan's just doesn't show anything at all

Comment: @davidjbeiler Interesting, and weird. What about doing `df.fillna(0).astype(int).values.ravel().tolist()`?

Comment: if i just do print(df) the output of the dataframe doesn't even include naan's, the csv document that i have either has 'incomplete' or 'complete' in the column im trying to analyze

Comment: @davidjbeiler I don't see that in your data, or your question, so could you open a new question with the relevant information? I can help you better that way.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48027808/how-can-i-get-values-from-my-sql-query-if-the-column-has-zero-value

Comment: @davidjbeiler Ah, I see it now. This appears to be an issue with your query, not with pandas. Sorry! SQL is not my expertise.

Comment: yeah! you helped though with the output of pandas though, so thank you!