# How can I get values from my SQL query if the column has zero value?

Tags: python, sqlite

Basically i have a training dataset, but i want it to show zero instead of it not showing at all

The following show's all incomplete and complete, but i want it show incomplete and from the departments that have zero incomplete as 0

This is what i have so far, i need it to show all, my coworker was trying to help me but had to leave, so i am asking you guys

```
Select distinct Department, Total FROM
(
Select Department, Total FROM

(
SELECT 'Incomplete' AS Status, department, count(*) as Total
FROM MyTable
WHERE CompletedTraining = 'Incomplete'
GROUP BY department
union all
Select 'Complete' AS Status, department, Count(*) as Total
FROM MyTable
WHERE CompletedTraining = ' Complete'
Group By Department
)
WHERE Status = 'Incomplete'
)
union all
SELECT DISTINCT Department, NULL AS Total
FROM MyTable
```

When I run my python script i get this

```
Incomplete Training
[6, 8, 2, 3, 6, 4, 4, 5, 2, 4]
```

but if someone took my training i want it to show zero in the list
so my expected output would be something like this

```
Incomplete Training
[6, 8, 2, 3, 6, 4, 4, 5, 2, 4, 0, 0]
```

Example document X 1500 rows with multiple users

```
Curriculum Name     Department          Employee Name           Employee Email  Employee Status Date Assigned   Completion Date CompletedTraining
Security Training   OIS John Doe        john.doe@email.org      Active  7/18/2017 21:47 8/2/2017 21:31                          Complete
Support Training    OIS Home Simpson    home.simpson@email.gov  Active  4/20/2017 15:33 5/3/2017 22:18                          Complete
Security Training   ASD bart simpson    bart.simpson@email.gove Active  5/5/2017 20:22  11/30/2017 19:43                        incomplete
Security Training   CO  jack johnson    jack.johnson@email.gov  Active  5/9/2017 21:15  5/10/2017 20:23                         incomplete
Security Training   ECARS    jack johnson   jack.johnson@email.gov  Active  5/9/2017 21:15  5/10/2017 20:23                         incomplete
Security Training   EO  jack johnson    jack.johnson@email.gov  Active  5/9/2017 21:15  5/10/2017 20:23                         incomplete
Security Training   ISD jack johnson    jack.johnson@email.gov  Active  5/9/2017 21:15  5/10/2017 20:23                         incomplete
Security Training   MSCD    jack johnson    jack.johnson@email.gov  Active  5/9/2017 21:15  5/10/2017 20:23                         incomplete
Security Training   RD  jack johnson    jack.johnson@email.gov  Active  5/9/2017 21:15  5/10/2017 20:23                         incomplete
Security Training   TTD jack johnson    jack.johnson@email.gov  Active  5/9/2017 21:15  5/10/2017 20:23                         incomplete
Security Training   DP  jack johnson    jack.johnson@email.gov  Active  5/9/2017 21:15  5/10/2017 20:23                         incomplete
Security Training   MLD jack johnson    jack.johnson@email.gov  Active  5/9/2017 21:15  5/10/2017 20:23                         incomplete
Security Training   OIS jack johnson    jack.johnson@email.gov  Active  5/9/2017 21:15  5/10/2017 20:23                         incomplete
Security Training   TTD jack johnson    jack.johnson@email.gov  Active  5/9/2017 21:15  5/10/2017 20:23                         incomplete
Security Training   TTD jack johnson    jack.johnson@email.gov  Active  5/9/2017 21:15  5/10/2017 20:23                         incomplete
Security Training   AQPSD jack johnson  jack.johnson@email.gov  Active  5/9/2017 21:15  5/10/2017 20:23                         incomplete
```

Comment: Can you give sample tables.

Comment: updated, basically i need my query to output all departments, and there are a toal of 13 departments

Comment: From your sample data of just those 4 rows, you'd expect OIS 0,ASD 1, TTD1?

Comment: i have 13 total departments, should i edit that in the example?

Comment: Check my answer for the incompletes. I am not sure it needs all of the unions. I'll keep an eye on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get you your incomplete #'s.

```
select distinct 
    Department
    , (select count(*) from MyTable t2 where t2.Department = t1.Department and t2.CompletedTraining='Incomplete') as Total
from MyTable t1
```

To get Incomplete and Completes on same row

```
select distinct 
    Department
    , (select count(*) from MyTable t2 where t2.Department = t1.Department and t2.CompletedTraining='Incomplete') as TotalIncomplete
    , (select count(*) from MyTable t2 where t2.Department = t1.Department and t2.CompletedTraining='Complete') as TotalComplete
from MyTable t1
```

or something like

```
select distinct 'Incomplete' as Src
    , Department
    , (select count(*) from MyTable t2 where t2.Department = t1.Department and t2.CompletedTraining='Incomplete') as Total
from MyTable t1
union
select distinct 'Complete' as Src
    , Department
    , (select count(*) from MyTable t2 where t2.Department = t1.Department and t2.CompletedTraining='Completeomplete') as Total
from MyTable t1
```

Comment: i dont want to rely on the department names if possible, i will try this

Comment: awesome!!! , i assume i can use that for complete too, just change the completedtraining='complete'?

Comment: what about complete training? i tried changing 'incomplete' to 'complete' and it didn't work...

Comment: Updated the answer, gl.

Comment: Hmm..., it didn't produce any results for "complete"

Comment: There is a leading space in the ' Complete' in your sample

Comment: last question, how can i not display the department name?