# How to get a python array from JSON

Tags: python, arrays, json

Can't solve how to convert JSON to python so that all data be in an array.
I used code to extract JSON, but the problem is that to extract strings from each new JSON data set is a new issue due to the inequality of the number of columns.

```
import json
data = open('acndata_sessions.json')
json.load(data)
```

I also tried to use https://app.quicktype.io/, but the function result is:

> data_from_dict(json.loads(json_string)) doesn't work.

Data set: [json](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1p_C8S5iLWa24wCshYRO0fap-z7DI-ZIc/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

This question seems to have been asked before. [Convert JSON array to Python list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10973614/convert-json-array-to-python-list)

They use 'json.loads' instead of 'json.load' which you use. Both are functions, but they are different.

Comment: This answer should be a flagged comment.

Answer (score 0):

I think your looking for something like this.

```
import json
with open('myfile.json','r') as jsonFile:
            pythonJSON=json.load(jsonFile)
        jsonFile.close()
print(pythonJSON.keys())
```

The `json.loads()` is used when you have a string type. If the example above doesn't work with just `json.load()` try it with `json.loads()`.

Answer (score 0):

`json.load` already gives you a dictionary. You just have to use it and iterate through `_items`

```
import json
data = open('acndata_sessions.json')
data_dict = json.load(data)

# Load items from dictionary
items = data_dict['_items']

# Iterate in items
for item in items:
    # Print the item
    print(item)
    # Or if you want to further iterate on user inputs present in this item
    user_inputs = item['userInputs']
    # Check if there are any user inputs present in this item
    if user_inputs:
        for user_input in user_inputs:
            print(user_input)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try checking this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10973614/convert-json-array-to-python-list#10973638). You can parse a json file like this:

```
import json

# read file
with open('example.json', 'r') as myfile:
    data=myfile.read()

# parse file
obj = json.loads(data)

# show values
print(str(obj['_items']))#returns a dict
print(str(obj['_meta']))
```