# How to work with JSON (JSONArray) in Python Processing

Tags: python, json, processing

This is an example copied from Java Processing tutorials and would like to have something like that in Python Processing.

```
    
String[] species = { "Capra hircus", "Panthera pardus", "Equus zebra" };
String[] names = { "Goat", "Leopard", "Zebra" };

JSONArray values;

void setup() {

  values = new JSONArray();

  for (int i = 0; i < species.length; i++) {

    JSONObject animal = new JSONObject();

    animal.setInt("id", i);
    animal.setString("species", species[i]);
    animal.setString("name", names[i]);

    values.setJSONObject(i, animal);
  }

  saveJSONArray(values, "data/new.json");
}
```

This is what I've already tried in Python.

```
import json

values = JSONArray

species = [ "Capra hircus", "Panthera pardus", "Equus zebra"]
names = [ "Goat", "Leopard", "Zebra" ]

def setup():
    for i in range(len(species)):
        animal = JSONObject

        animal.setInt("id", i)
        animal.setString("species", species[i])
        animal.setString("name", names[i])

        values.setJSONObject(i, animal)

    saveJSONArray(values, "data/new.json")
```

After running the program I'm  getting the following error:
`NameError: name 'JSONArray' is not defined`

I know there should be another way of declaring JSON object in Python Processing but I am new to Python so I have no idea what the mistake could be.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

**values ==JSONArray is completely wrong** There is no declared like that in python.

I guess First you should check python tutorials. For your question

```
array = '{"fruits": ["apple", "banana", "orange"]}'
data  = json.loads(array)
print data['fruits']
```

is a good example for your problem.

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10973614/convert-json-array-to-python-list) is a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
import json

annotations = [0,1,2]
species = [ "Capra hircus", "Panthera pardus", "Equus zebra"]
names = [ "Goat", "Leopard", "Zebra" ]


def setup(anotations, species, names):
    values = []

    for idx, _ in enumerate(annotations):
        animal = {
            "id": idx,
            "species": species[idx],
            "name": names[idx]
        }

        values.append(animal)

    with open("data_file.json", "w") as write_file:
      json.dump(values, write_file)


if __name__ == "__main__":
  setup(annotations, species, names)
```