# Issue Converting JSON String Back into Python List (Due to HTML within the JSON)

Tags: python, json

How to convert the below string into a list in Python?

The HTML within the list is making it difficult.

```
jsonObj = json.dumps("[[\"Item1/\", \"<!DOCTYPE html><html lang=\\\"en-US\\\"><head> <script type=\\\"text/javascript\\\">\\nvar gform;gform||(document.\", \"no script tags\", 200], [\"item2/\", \"<!DOCTYPE html><html lang=\\\"en-US\\\"><head> <script type=\\\"text/javascript\\\">\\nvar gform;gform||(document.\", \"no script tags\", 200], [\"item3/\", \"<!DOCTYPE html><html lang=\\\"en-US\\\"><head> <script type=\\\"text/javascript\\\">\\nvar gform;gform||(document.\", \"no script tags\", 200]]" )

# convert strObj to list of lists
listObj = json.loads(jsonObj)

print(type(listObj)) # returns <class 'str'>
```

The above returns a string, but ideally want it to return a list.

Comment: hi, perhaps might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10973614/convert-json-array-to-python-list

Comment: json.loads() doesn't work, at least not in the returned values current form. The HTML object within the list seems to be the problem making json.loads() not properly converting to list, but I haven't been able to figure out a solution to that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert JSON array to Python list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10973614/convert-json-array-to-python-list)

Comment: Also, I think the problem is you're only using one slash; use two backslashes to escape it in JSON (that is, JSON uses one but you need two because it's a python string)

Comment: Realized my initial question didn't correctly represent the problem based on the note above from pigrammer. I went ahead and adjusted.

Answer (score 0):

Issue: When dumping any string with `json.dumps("")` the function will return an object of class or type `str`, like the actual in `jsonObj`.

### Reading JSON strings in Python

The use of Python's JSON module, function load-string `json.loads()` is correct.

You can apply two best-practices for working with JSON strings:

1. Use another quote-character to enclose the string. Inside JSON the double-quote is used. So surround your string with a different: single-quotes
2. Use the [raw-string prefix `r`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) before the first quote of the string literal. This way all special control-chars inside the string can be interpreted correctly.

#### Working Code

```py
import json

# use raw string with single-quotes to assign the JSON
json_str = r'[["item4", "<!DOCTYPE html><html lang=\"en-US\"><head> <script type=\"text/javascript\">\nvar gform;gform||(document.", "no script tags", 200], ["item3", "<!DOCTYPE html><html lang=\"en-US\"><head> <script type=\"text/javascript\">\nvar gform;gform||(document.", "no script tags", 200], ["item2", "<!DOCTYPE html><html lang=\"en-US\"><head> <script type=\"text/javascript\">\nvar gform;gform||(document.", "no script tags", 200], ["item1", "<!DOCTYPE html><html lang=\"en-US\"><head> <script type=\"text/javascript\">\nvar gform;gform||(document.", "no script tags", 200]]'

# parse JSON string
obj = json.loads(json_str)

# the result is a Python list
print(type(obj))  # debug-print the type: list
print(len(obj))  # debug-print the length of the list
print(obj)  # debug-print the value of the list
```

### Issues and Troubleshooting

#### With escaped double-quotes inside JSON

```
json_str_quotes_escaped = r'[[\"Item1/\", \"<!DOCTYPE html><html lang=\\\"en-US\\\"><head> <script type=\\\"text/javascript\\\">\\nvar gform;gform||(document.\", \"no script tags\", 200], [\"item2/\", \"<!DOCTYPE html><html lang=\\\"en-US\\\"><head> <script type=\\\"text/javascript\\\">\\nvar gform;gform||(document.\", \"no script tags\", 200], [\"item3/\", \"<!DOCTYPE html><html lang=\\\"en-US\\\"><head> <script type=\\\"text/javascript\\\">\\nvar gform;gform||(document.\", \"no script tags\", 200]]'
```

The escaping backslash before the double-quotes `r'[[\"` is not allowed inside JSON - if it is not used inside a string-value. Because we escape the property-name `"Item1"`, we get this error:

> json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 3 (char 2)

It is exactly pointing to the column 3 or char at position 3 inside the JSON string, hence the first backslash `\` before the field-definition.

Make sure you use a valid JSON string.

#### Escaping backslash inside JSON text values

A valid JSON may use escaping backslash before double-quotes only inside text-values to represent a raw double-quote character inside a text.

Example: Valid JSON defining a text with a double-quote inside

```json
{"message": "The speaker said: \"Hello World!\""}
```

Can be parsed to print the message as:

> The speaker said: "Hello World!"

#### With inappropriate string-definition

Without the raw-string prefix we get following error:

> json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 40 (char 39)

When using double-quotes to define the string, we get this error:

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax